# How do I use value of one method in another. I am getting AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'auth_header'

Tags: python, python-unittest

Here is my code (single class A)

```
class A(page):

   def test_auth(self):
       params = {
           'email': 'zzzm',
           'password': 'yyyy',
       }

       response = self.send_request(self.request_auth,
                                         request_type=self.request_type_post,
                                         headers=self.header_content_type_x_www_form_urlencoded,
                                         data=params,
                                         need_headers=True)

       auth_header = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {response['headers']['x-api-token']}"}
```

## Method to get the profile using above generated auth code

```
def test_profile(self):
    auth_header = self.auth_header
    response = self.send_request(self.request_profile,
                                         auth=auth_header,
                                         headers=self.header_accept_json
                                         )
```

The error I'm getting AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'auth_header'

Can someone help me how can I use the value generated in the first method in another method of the same class? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The method `test_profile` is part of the class `A`?

Comment: You didn't define it as an attribute, you just defined it as `auth_header`. Define the dictionary as `self.auth_header` in `test_auth`... assuming both methods are in the same class.

Comment: you are defining  `auth_header` in the second function, your request you the latest `auth_header` which is second one, try remove the `auth_header = self.auth_header`

Comment: What @roganjosh said. `auth_header` is just a local name inside the `test_auth` method, it doesn't exist outside that method.

Comment: @ThatBird yes its same class

Comment: @ZmnakoAwrahman if i remove `auth_header` I get `NameError: name 'auth_header' is not defined`

Comment: @roganjosh  I have tried it in this way ` self.auth_header = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {response['headers']['x-api-token']}"}` and use it in second method as `auth=self.auth_header,`. didnt work . same error

Comment: That depends on which order you run the methods. You would have to run `test_auth()` before `test_profile()` in order for it to exist.

Comment: @roganjosh ok. What do you suggest? run it in a suite?

Comment: I mean it really depends on what you want to do. If you need `auth_header` to be available in multiple of your methods, you might be better creating it in the constructor `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like -

```
class A(page):

    def test_auth(self):
        params = {
            'email': 'zzzm',
            'password': 'yyyy',
        }

        response = self.send_request(self.request_auth,
                                     request_type=self.request_type_post,                                         
        headers=self.header_content_type_x_www_form_urlencoded,
                                     data=params,
                                     need_headers=True)
        auth_header = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {response['headers']['x-api-token']}"}
        return auth_header


    def test_profile(self):
        auth_header = self.test_auth()
        response = self.send_request(self.request_profile,
                                     auth=auth_header,
                                     headers=self.header_accept_json
                                     )
```

Or put things in init like -

```
class A(page):
    def test_auth(self):
        params = {
            'email': 'zzzm',
            'password': 'yyyy',
        }

        response = self.send_request(self.request_auth,
                                     request_type=self.request_type_post,                                         
        headers=self.header_content_type_x_www_form_urlencoded,
                                     data=params,
                                     need_headers=True)
        auth_header = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {response['headers']['x-api-token']}"}
        return auth_header

    def __init__(self, page):
        self.auth_header = self.test_auth()


    def test_profile(self):
        auth_header = self.auth_header
        response = self.send_request(self.request_profile,
                                     auth=auth_header,
                                     headers=self.header_accept_json
                                     )
```

Perk of putting things in `__init__` is you can use it throughout your class.

Comment: this one was perfect. I see you updated it with `return` statement. This gave me the idea for future. thanks a lot! appreciate it!